# Quick question about proving that $f(x)$ is irreducible over $D[x]$ if it is irreducible over $Q[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, irreducible-polynomials

Let D be a UFD, $Q$ be the quotient field of D and $f(x)$ be a primitive polynomial in $D[x]$. I have a quick question about proving: $f(x)$ is irreducible in $Q[x]$ $\rightarrow$ $f(x)$ is irreducible in $D[x]$.

I've seen a proof for this and I can follow every step of it. But I don't understand why you can't simply argue that this statement is equivalent to the contrapositive statement saying:

$f(x)$ is reducible in $D[x]$ $\rightarrow$ $f(x)$ is reducible in $Q[x]$.

Isn't this statement obviously true, since if $f(x)$ is reducible in $D[x]$ it can be factored into polynomials of lower degree in $D[x]$ and this is also a factorization of $f(x)$ into polynomials of lower degree in $Q[x]$, (since $D[x]$ $\subseteq$ $Q[x]$) hence $f(x)$ is reducible in $Q[x]$?

Is there something that I'm missing?

Thankful for any help!

Comment: I think you have the statement backwards.  The statement I've seen is "$f(x)$ reducible in $Q[x]$ $\Rightarrow$ $f(x)$ reducible in $D[x]$", which is equivalent to "$f(x)$ irreducible in $D[x]$ $\Rightarrow$ $f(x)$ irreducible in $Q[x]$."

Comment: No, the statement I wrote is what I meant. But the theorem goes both ways, so probably that's why you've seen the statement that you wrote.

Comment: Okay, so you've just written the easy direction then.  The one I mention is the more difficult one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right.

One thing you missed is that a polynomial which is not irreducible in $D[x]$ might be factored into an irreducible constant (constants are not necessarily units in $D$) and a polynomial, however now this case is impossible since $f$ is primitive. All these are obvious though.

Under your setting, the statement can be strengthen as: $f$ is irreducible in $D[x]$ if and only if $f$ is irreducible in $Q[x]$.

I guess what makes the proof long you saw might possibly provide a proof that if $f$ is irreducible in $D[x]$ then it is also irreducible in $Q[x]$ ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not quite sure that I understand though. Is the point that I'm missing that an irreducible polynomial over $D[x]$ is not the same as an irreducible polynomial over $Q[x]$? I mean even if a polynomial in $D[x]$ is factored into a constant times another polynomial, this isn't a factorization into polynomials of lower degree - which it has to be in order to be reducible, right? Or is the notion of irreducible/reducible polynomial different when the polynomial is over a ring and not a field...?

Comment: Here can be found the definition of an irreducible element in a domain: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreducible_element

Comment: $2x$ is not irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ but irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$.

Comment: Thanks, that was the key point that I was missing!